# How can I do to remove the last |?

Tags: regex

Hello I have this text :

```
a | b | c | d
d | 3 | r | 9
r | r| 8 | u
```

and I would like using a regex this :

```
a | b | c  d
d | 3 | r  9
r | r| 8  u
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern: `^(.+)\|(.+)$`

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of the string

`(.+)\|` - `.+` matches one or more of any character until **last** (because greedy quantifier is used) occurence of `|`, which is matched by `\|` and stores it in first capturing group

`(.+)$` - match one or more of any characters, until the end of sstring `$`

And replace the string with this pattern: `\1\2`. `\1` references first capturing group, `\2` - second capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBjJzr/1)

Answer (score 1):

Match the last | with `(\|)(?=[^|]*$)`

This translates to matching a | ,followed by any number of non-|, meaning it is the last.